# Using an API to calculate distance between two airports (two columns) within R?

Tags: r, rcurl, httr

I was wondering whether there was a way to compare airport distances(IATA codes). There are some scripts but not is using R. So I tried that with with the API:

[developer.aero](https://www.developer.aero/Airport-API/API-Overview)

Example data:

```
library(curl) # for curl post

departure <- c("DRS","TXL","STR","DUS","LEJ","FKB","LNZ")
arrival <- c("FKB","HER","BOJ","FUE","PMI","AYT","FUE")
flyID <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7)
df <- data.frame(departure,arrival,flyID)  

     departure arrival flyID
1       DRS     FKB     1
2       TXL     HER     2
3       STR     BOJ     3
4       DUS     FUE     4
5       LEJ     PMI     5
6       FKB     AYT     6
7       LNZ     FUE     7

api<- curl_fetch_memory("https://airport.api.aero/airport/distance/DRS/FUE?user_key=d805e84363494ca03b9b52d5a505c4d1")

cat(rawToChar(api$content))

callback({"processingDurationMillis":0,"authorisedAPI":true,"success":true,"airline":null,"errorMessage":null,"distance":"3,416.1","units":"km"})
```

where DRS corresponds to departure and FUE arrival airport

So I though to loop over `df`and paste into url. However that seems somehow difficult for a R - Newbie

```
df$distance<- list(length = nrow(df))
for (i in 1:nrow(df)){
  url <- paste0("https://airport.api.aero/airport/distance/", i, "FUE   ?user_key=d805e84363494ca03b9b52d5a505c4d1")
  myData[[i]] <- read.table(url, header=T,sep="|")
}
```

Desired Output:

```
departure arrival flyID    distance
1       DRS     FKB     1    1000
2       TXL     HER     2    499
3       STR     BOJ     3    300
4       DUS     FUE     4    200
5       LEJ     PMI     5    586
6       FKB     AYT     6   10292
7       LNZ     FUE     7   3939
```

Comment: Do you get the distances when running `read.table` and your question is how to save them in a data.frame? Or do you only get the geocoordinates of the airports and your question is about how to transforme them into distances? Or is your question about linking the IATA codes to geocoordinates?

Comment: If there had been any positive response to request for clarification would not have joined the closevote suggestion, but with the error thrown by the second section of code it really is unclear what is asked.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's another way with the `httr` package:

```
library(httr)

callAPI <- function(from, to) {
  res <- GET("https://airport.api.aero",
             path = paste0("airport/distance/", from, "/", to),
             query = list(user_key = "d805e84363494ca03b9b52d5a505c4d1"))
  stop_for_status(res)
  return(content(res, encoding = "UTF-8"))
}


test <- callAPI("DRS", "FKB")
# test
test$distance
# [1] "484.6"

for (i in 1:nrow(df)) {
  from = df[i, "departure"]
  to = df[i, "arrival"]
  df[i, "distance"] <- callAPI(from, to)$distance
}

#   departure arrival flyID distance
# 1       DRS     FKB     1    484.6
# 2       TXL     HER     2  2,131.8
# 3       STR     BOJ     3  1,575.0
# 4       DUS     FUE     4  3,066.3
# 5       LEJ     PMI     5  1,512.4
# 6       FKB     AYT     6  2,264.2
# 7       LNZ     FUE     7  3,258.0
```

---

If you want to get the full results, you could use:

```
all_results <- mapply(function(x,y) { callAPI(x,y) }, df$departure, df$arrival)
cbind(df, t(all_results))
#   departure arrival flyID processingDurationMillis authorisedAPI success airline errorMessage distance units
# 1       DRS     FKB     1                        0          TRUE    TRUE    NULL         NULL    484.6    km
# 2       TXL     HER     2                        0          TRUE    TRUE    NULL         NULL  2,131.8    km
# 3       STR     BOJ     3                        0          TRUE    TRUE    NULL         NULL  1,575.0    km
# 4       DUS     FUE     4                        0          TRUE    TRUE    NULL         NULL  3,066.3    km
# 5       LEJ     PMI     5                        0          TRUE    TRUE    NULL         NULL  1,512.4    km
# 6       FKB     AYT     6                        0          TRUE    TRUE    NULL         NULL  2,264.2    km
# 7       LNZ     FUE     7                        1          TRUE    TRUE    NULL         NULL  3,258.0    km
```

Comment: May I ask you one additional info on how to adjust the for loop if the distance between aiports is "NULL". I suppose the loop will stop. Thank you again!

Comment: @MichaerMacher I would advise asking this as a new question. In addition, You could probably change the last two lines of the `for` loop to: `distance <- ifelse(is.null(callAPI(from, to)$distance), NA, callAPI(from, to)$distance)` and `df[i, "distance"] <- distance`. This way you would return an `NA` to investigate.

Answer (score 8):

You can do this without an API, just using the co-ordinates of airports, which are available freely in a database here https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jpatokal/openflights/master/data/airports.dat

```
## Import airport data
airports <- read.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jpatokal/openflights/master/data/airports.dat", header = F)

library(geosphere)
## Calculate matrix of differences in km
distance.matrix <- distm(x = airports[,c("V8", "V7")],  y = airports[,c("V8", "V7")])/1000
## This may take a while, and will generate a matrix 8107 by 8107, about 0.5gb in size.

## Rename dimensions to airport codes
rownames(distance.matrix) <- airports$V5
colnames(distance.matrix) <- airports$V5

## Example: km between Gatwick and Heathrow
distance.matrix["LGW", "LHR"]
[1] 41.24091
```

Answer (score 1):

What about the following loop over your api calls?

```
df$distance <- 0

for (i in nrow(df)){
  drs <- df[i,]$departure
  fue <- df[i,]$arrival
  url <- paste0("https://airport.api.aero/airport/distance/", drs, "/", fue, "?user_key=4e816a2bf391f8379df1c42d2762069e")
  api <- curl_fetch_memory(url)
  text <- rawToChar(api$content)
  distance <- as.numeric(gsub(',','',substr(text,regexpr('distance',text)+11,regexpr('units',text)-4)))
  df[1,]$distance <- distance
}

df
```