# R- Scraping Wikipedia list in to a table

Tags: r, web-scraping, wikipedia

I am trying to create a table of U.S. hub airports from the list on the Wikipedia page (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_hub_airports) using R. I am new to web scraping, so any help or advice on this would be appreciated. I am trying to get a table similar to the following with the information from every U.S. state.

[Example of airport hub table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aKCWH.png)

Thanks!

Comment: This question is very broad. Pulling the data and parsing is a project in itself. Please do not ask someone to complete your work for you. This is not a code-writing service. If you would like a general tip on one aspect of the project that you have been having particular trouble with, please limit your question to that.

Comment: if you are just looking for information concerning airport locations, you might want to consider this question and answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37572731/using-an-api-to-calculate-distance-between-two-airports-two-columns-within-r

Comment: This is the kind of assignment that [experienced R users would be happy to do for you.](https://www.r-users.com/)

Comment: Thank you for the comments and the code below, it helped clarify how to parse the web page. I admit I wrote the question in haste, and that I should have taken the time to make the question more focused. I was not looking to get some else to do the work, as I said I am new to web scraping and I was looking advice on how someone might approach this particular issue. Thank you again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although the entire project will be a challenge, here is a start to pull the US data.

```
library(rvest)
site <- "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_hub_airports"
txt <- read_html(site) %>%
  html_nodes("#mw-content-text :nth-child(1)") %>%
  html_text()
usatext <- txt[1866:2329]
```